# Javascript validate string is a character followed by numbers

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate a string where the first character must be an `'x'` and the remaining characters must be numerical. For example:

```
x1234 == true;
k1234 == false;
x12k4 == false;
1x123 == false;
```

Here is my code:

```
function isValidCode(code){
    var firstLetter = code.substring(0,1);
    var remainingCode = code.substring(1);
    var validCode = false;

    // Debugging
    console.log(firstLetter);
    console.log(remainingCode);

    if(firstLetter == 'x'){
        validCode = true;
    }
    if(isNumeric(Number(remainingCode))){
        validCode = true;
    }
}
```

I've debugged my `isNumeric()` function, so I'm 99.9% sure the issue isn't there, but here it is just in case:

```
function isNumeric(numberIn)
{
    var returnValue = true;

    if (isNaN(numberIn) || isNaN(parseInt(numberIn, 10)))
    {
        returnValue = false;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I've tried several things such as reversing my logic where I start with the given condidtion being true and then checking `if(!(firstLetter == 'x'))` I've tried `==` and `===`and I've tried casting the remaining portion of the code with `Number()` , `+()` and not casting it at all, but none of these seeem to do the trick. The console does log the proper first character and remaining characters in the code so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression test:

```
function isValidCode(code) {
    return /^[a-z]\d+$/.test(code);
}
```

I am making an assumption that a lower case letter is required, followed by at least one digit.

To match only only the letter 'x', use:

```
function isValidCode(code) {
    return /^x\d+$/.test(code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and is much cleaner it does accept any letter at the moment, but I can fix that. I'll accept it in 5 minutes when I can. As an aside, any idea why the original code wasn't working?

Comment: Number("") will be converted to 0.  When `remainingCode` is "", 0 is being passed into isNumeric, which is returning true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/^x(?=\d+$)/` to match `x` at beginning of input followed by digits followed by end of input

```js
var arr = ["x1234"
, "k1234"
, "x12k4"
, "1x123"];

var re = /^x(?=\d+$)/;

arr.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(`${str}: ${re.test(str)}`)
})
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for including tge test cases, unfortunately dave beat you by a few minutes.